# How to sort an array in Swift with numbers and letters

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, nsarray

I got an array like, using Swift 1.2

```
var anArray = ["500", "200B, "200A", "1", "90B"]
```

Then start of the string is always a number from 1 to 999. Sometimes, there is a letter at the end that could be a 'A' or a 'B'

I would like to sort it by numbers then by letters :

```
["1", "90B", "200A", "200B", "500"]
```

I try to use sort/sorted method but the order is wrong.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209195/sorting-array-alphabetically-with-number

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, sorry for the duplicate!

Comment: let sortedArray = anArray.sorted{$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending}