# abnormal sorting in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, swift3

Sorted func in swift has improper sorting.

unsorted objects

> ["9", "7", "3", "8", "6", "2", "4", "10", "5"]

sorted objects

> [**"10"**, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

code :

```
print("unsorted objects",students.map{($0 as! EX_STUDENT).roll_no!})

studentList = students.sorted{($0 as! EX_STUDENT).roll_no! < ($1 as! EX_STUDENT).roll_no!}

print("sorted objects",studentList.map{($0 as! EX_STUDENT).roll_no!})
```

why is 10 at 0th index?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39748677/4601170

Comment: You are sorting strings, not integer

Comment: true because i want alphanumeric sorting, and i want it in ascending order too. ex roll no can be RX00012,RX00034

Comment: If all numbers are padded with zeros to the same length then the problem should not occur. What is an *actual* example of wrong sorting in your case?

Comment: well its varies alot. Consider that am working with a lot of schools and every school has different roll no, it can be number or alphanumeric

Comment: The linked-to Q&A shows methods to sort strings based on the numerical value of embedded numbers. If that does not work for you then please provide a *concrete example* of input, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localizedStandardCompare to sort your strings numerically:

```
let numbers = ["9", "7", "3", "8", "6", "2", "4", "10", "5"]

let numericSort = numbers.sorted{$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}

numericSort  // ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

Comment: it doesn't works, same output

Comment: Define what `doesn't work`. sorted is a non mutating method

Comment: i know that already, if you noticed my code, there are two references students and studenList. am assigning students sorted objects to studentList

Comment: The result it is properly sorted here

Comment: well in my case it like this, studentList = students.sorted{(($0 as! EX_STUDENT).roll_no!).localizedCompare(($1 as! EX_STUDENT).roll_no!) == .orderedAscending }

Comment: Ohh.. sorry i get it. i was using localizedCompare not localizedStandardCompare.