# Swift sort an array with strings and numbers

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

I have an array of strings,

```
let array = [ "10", "1", "101", "NA", "100", "20", "210", "200", "NA", "7" ]
```

I would like to get the output sorted in ascending as,

```
let sorted = [ "1", "7", "10", "20", "100", "101", "200", "210", "NA", "NA" ]
```

I tried using the sorted command but it does not work when it encounters more than 2 digits e.g.: 100, 101, 200 etc.

```
array.sorted { $0? < $1? }
```

What would be the simple way to get this?

Answer (score 102):

edit/update:
**Xcode 12 • Swift 5.5 (iOS 15 • iPadOS 15 • macOS 12 • Mac Catalyst 15 • tvOS 15 • watchOS 8 • visionOS 1 Beta) or later**

For sorting just an array of strings you can use `String.Comparator.localizedStandard`:

```
var array = [ "10", "1", "101", "NA", "100", "20", "210", "200", "NA", "7" ]
array.sort(using: .localizedStandard)
print(array)  // ["1", "7", "10", "20", "100", "101", "200", "210", "NA", "NA"]
```

---

If you need to reverse the sort order:

```
extension SortComparator {
    var reverse: Self  {
        var reverse = self
        reverse.order = .reverse
        return reverse
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
array.sort(using: .localizedStandard.reverse)
print(array)  // ["NA", "NA", "210", "200", "101", "100", "20", "10", "7", "1"]
```

---

If you need more control over the sorting options you can use the [`String.Comparator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/comparator/init(options:locale:order:)):

```
init(
    options: String.CompareOptions,
    locale: Locale? = Locale.current,
    order: SortOrder = .forward
)
```

---

Usage:

```
array.sort(
    using: String.Comparator(
        options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive, .numeric],
        order: .reverse
    )
)

print(array)  // ["NA", "NA", "210", "200", "101", "100", "20", "10", "7", "1"]
```

---

For sorting custom objects you can use `KeyPathComparator` and pass `localizedStandard` as the `Comparator`:

Playground testing

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age : Int
}

extension Person : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "name: \(name), age: \(age)" }
}

people.sort(using: KeyPathComparator(\.name, comparator: .localizedStandard))
print(people) // [name: Bono, age: 57, name: Éd Sheeran, age: 26, name: phil Collins, age: 66, name: rihanna, age: 25, name: Shakira, age: 40]
people.sort(using: KeyPathComparator(\.name, comparator: .localizedStandard, order: .reverse))
print(people) // "[name: Shakira, age: 40, name: rihanna, age: 25, name: phil Collins, age: 66, name: Éd Sheeran, age: 26, name: Bono, age: 57]"
```

Note: You can use multiple Sort Comparators if needed.

---

You can also use `KeyPathComparator` when sorting simple collections, you just need to pass `self` for the `KeyPath`:

```
array.sort(using: KeyPathComparator(\.self, comparator: .localizedStandard, order: .reverse))
print(array)  // ["NA", "NA", "210", "200", "101", "100", "20", "10", "7", "1"]
```

---

Older Swift versions

**Xcode 11.3 • Swift 5.2 or later**

You can use String method `localizedStandardCompare` (diacritics and case insensitive):

```
let array = [ "10", "1", "101", "NA", "100", "20", "210", "200", "NA", "7" ]
let sorted = array.sorted {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}

print(sorted) // ["1", "7", "10", "20", "100", "101", "200", "210", "NA", "NA"]
```

---

or using the method `sort(by:)` on a MutableCollection:

```
var array = [ "10", "1", "101", "NA", "100", "20", "210", "200", "NA", "7" ]
array.sort {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}

print(array) // ["1", "7", "10", "20", "100", "101", "200", "210", "NA", "NA"]
```

---

You can also implement your own localized standard sort method extending Collection:

```
public extension Sequence where Element: StringProtocol {
     func localizedStandardSorted(ascending: Bool = true) -> [Element] {
        let result: ComparisonResult = ascending ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending
        return sorted { $0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == result }
    }
}
```

---

```
let array = [ "10", "1", "101", "NA", "100", "20", "210", "200", "NA", "7" ]
let sorted = array.localizedStandardSorted()

print(sorted) // ["1", "7", "10", "20", "100", "101", "200", "210", "NA", "NA"]
```

---

The mutating method as well extending MutableCollection:

```
public extension MutableCollection where Element: StringProtocol, Self: RandomAccessCollection {
    mutating func localizedStandardSort(ascending: Bool = true) {
        let result: ComparisonResult = ascending ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending
        return sort { $0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == result }
    }
}
```

---

```
var array = [ "10", "1", "101", "NA", "100", "20", "210", "200", "NA", "7" ]
array.localizedStandardSort()

print(array) // ["1", "7", "10", "20", "100", "101", "200", "210", "NA", "NA"]
```

If you need to sort your array numerically you can use String compare method setting the options parameter to `.numeric`:

```
public extension Sequence where Element: StringProtocol {
    func sortedNumerically(ascending: Bool = true) -> [Element] {
        let result: ComparisonResult = ascending ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending
        return sorted { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == result }
    }
}
```

---

```
public extension MutableCollection where Element: StringProtocol, Self: RandomAccessCollection {
    mutating func sortNumerically(ascending: Bool = true) {
        let result: ComparisonResult = ascending ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending
        return sort { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == result }
    }
}
```

---

```
var numbers = ["1.5","0.5","1"]
let sortedNumbers = numbers.sortedNumerically()
print(sortedNumbers)  // ["0.5", "1", "1.5"]
print(numbers) // ["1.5","0.5","1"]
// mutating the original collection
numbers.sortNumerically(ascending: false)
print(numbers)  // "["1.5", "1", "0.5"]\n"
```

---

---

To sort a custom class/structure by one of its properties:

---

```
extension MutableCollection where Self: RandomAccessCollection {
    public mutating func localizedStandardSort<T: StringProtocol>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T, ascending: Bool = true) {
        sort {
            predicate($0).localizedStandardCompare(predicate($1)) ==
                (ascending ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public extension Sequence {
    func localizedStandardSorted<T: StringProtocol>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T, ascending: Bool = true) -> [Element] {
        sorted {
            predicate($0).localizedStandardCompare(predicate($1)) ==
                (ascending ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public extension Sequence {
    func sortedNumerically<T: StringProtocol>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T, ascending: Bool = true) -> [Element] {
        let result: ComparisonResult = ascending ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending
        return sorted { predicate($0).compare(predicate($1), options: .numeric) == result }
    }
}
```

---

```
public extension MutableCollection where Element: StringProtocol, Self: RandomAccessCollection {
    mutating func sortNumerically<T: StringProtocol>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T, ascending: Bool = true) {
        let result: ComparisonResult = ascending ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending
        return sort { predicate($0).compare(predicate($1), options: .numeric) == result }
    }
}
```

---

---

Playground testing

```
var people: [Person] = [.init(name: "Éd Sheeran", age: 26),
                        .init(name: "phil Collins", age: 66),
                        .init(name: "Shakira", age: 40),
                        .init(name: "rihanna", age: 25),
                        .init(name: "Bono", age: 57)]

let sorted = people.localizedStandardSorted(\.name)

print(sorted) // [name: Bono, age: 57, name: Éd Sheeran, age: 26, name: phil Collins, age: 66, name: rihanna, age: 25, name: Shakira, age: 40]
```

Comment: Nice. That also takes care of sorting local characters, i.e. ö is not sorted with o.