# How to Sort Dictionary by Key of Strings?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift4

I am using this code to sort a dictionary:

```
var sortedArray = dict.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
```

and it is sorting but not the way I would like it to see below:

```
["1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

insead of

```
 ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
```

full dict:

```
["17": 00:00:89, "12": 00:00:89, "20": 00:00:89, "23": 00:00:89, "19": 00:00:89, "22": 00:00:89, "13": 00:00:89, "9": 00:00:00, "8": 00:00:00, "6": 00:00:89, "7": 00:17:13, "name": G. Snyder, "24": 00:00:89, "14": 00:00:89, "16": 00:00:89, "18": 00:00:89, "15": 00:00:89, "2": 00:02:02, "11": 00:00:89, "1": 00:01:01, "3": 00:01:59, "4": 00:03:12, "21": 00:00:89, "10": 00:00:33, "5": 00:06:15]
```

EDIT: (still not working)

```
var sortedArray = dict.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
sortedArray.removeLast()
sortedArray = dict.sorted(by: {Int($0.0)! < Int($1.0)!})
```

Comment: that is the lexicographical order since you are dealing with strings, not numbers - `"2"` is "bigger" than `"19"`.

Comment: @luk2302 Ah, ok. So what would I need to do to change that?

Comment: Could you add the `dict`? it would be more clear...

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870210/2442804 or try moving away from Strings and just use Ints instead.

Comment: @luk2302 The dict is fetched from firebase and only allows me to store Strings

Comment: @AhmadF edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the logic of how [sorted(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2298238-sorted) is doing the comparison is related to the logic of the equality of the given elements, (you cannot sort an array of non-comparable elements), the output would be based on how *strings* comparing should be -since the given `dict` keys are strings- ("1" character is less than "2").

However, you might need to cast the key values to Ints and then sort:

```
let sorted = dict.sorted {
    if let key1Int = Int($0.key), let key2Int = Int($1.key) {
        return key1Int < key2Int
    }

    return true
}
```

At this point the sort should be valid even if the key value is uncastable to Int.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your dictionary keys using generic instance method [localizedStandardCompare](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923415-localizedstandardcompare)

> This method should be used whenever file names or other strings are
>   presented in lists and tables where Finder-like sorting is
>   appropriate. The exact sorting behavior of this method is different
>   under different locales and may be changed in future releases. This
>   method uses the current locale.

```
let dict = ["17": "00:00:89", "12": "00:00:89", "20": "00:00:89", "23": "00:00:89", "19": "00:00:89", "22": "00:00:89", "13": "00:00:89", "9": "00:00:00", "8": "00:00:00", "6": "00:00:89", "7": "00:17:13", "name": "G. Snyder", "24": "00:00:89", "14": "00:00:89", "16": "00:00:89", "18": "00:00:89", "15": "00:00:89", "2": "00:02:02", "11": "00:00:89", "1": "00:01:01", "3": "00:01:59", "4": "00:03:12", "21": "00:00:89", "10": "00:00:33", "5": "00:06:15"]

let sortedTuples = dict.sorted{$0.key.localizedStandardCompare($1.key) == .orderedAscending}
sortedTuples  // [(key "1", value "00:01:01"), (key "2", value "00:02:02"), (key "3", value "00:01:59"), (key "4", value "00:03:12"), (key "5", value "00:06:15"), (key "6", value "00:00:89"), (key "7", value "00:17:13"), (key "8", value "00:00:00"), (key "9", value "00:00:00"), (key "10", value "00:00:33"), (key "11", value "00:00:89"), (key "12", value "00:00:89"), (key "13", value "00:00:89"), (key "14", value "00:00:89"), (key "15", value "00:00:89"), (key "16", value "00:00:89"), (key "17", value "00:00:89"), (key "18", value "00:00:89"), (key "19", value "00:00:89"), (key "20", value "00:00:89"), (key "21", value "00:00:89"), (key "22", value "00:00:89"), (key "23", value "00:00:89"), (key "24", value "00:00:89"), (key "name", value "G. Snyder")]
```

Answer (score -1):

As your Dictionary consists of Strings, those are sorted alphabetically. What you could try is something like this:

```
let sortedArray = dict.sorted(by: {Int($0.0)! < Int($1.0)!})
```

Edit:
If not all the keys are sure to be convertible to numbers, we have to make it more complicated:

```
let sortedArray = dict.sorted(by: {
  let a = Int($0.0) ?? 0
  let b = Int($1.0) ?? 0
  return a < b
})
```

This puts the „name“ in your Dictionary to the top.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @WillMays Okay, so this solution still needs work ...

Comment: @WillMays Oh, it‘s because one of the keys is "name". Is that intentional?

Comment: See updated question

Comment: @WillMays I edited my answer to take that into account. By now I’ve also been able to test my code. But note that one of your values doesn‘t seem to be valid (G. Snyder). If you want to keep it, all your values must be Strings ("0.34", "G. Snyder" etc.).

Comment: error: expected ',' separator
}
 ^
 ,

Comment: For a few minutes there was a „)“ missing. It works now.