# Sorting an array containing strings and integers by multiple properties

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of `SortedELRStructure` that I need to sort by it's `elr` property, AS WELL AS by it's `railwayID`. The trouble I am having is the `railwayID` is populated using a string value, as it could be anything like ["1A", "C0284", "300000"] etc so when I sort the array by railwayID is sorts them as strings and I get back ["101023", "10A", "11", "12", "110032"] (example).

How do I sort an array of this type by the numerical value of `railwayID`, even when it contains letters, in addition to sorting by the `elr` string?

I've tried the following so far, which I think getting close but the railway ID is still being sorted as a string:

```
let sorted = sortedDayListItems.sorted { t1, t2 in
    if t1.elr == t2.elr {
        if t1.railwayID.isInt && t2.railwayID.isInt {
            return Int(t1.railwayID)! < Int(t2.railwayID)!
        } else {
                 
        }
        return t1.railwayID < t2.railwayID
    }
    return (t1.elr != nil) && (t2.elr == nil)
}

struct SortedELRStructure {
    var dataItem: CalendarSurveyDataItem
    var elr: String
    var railwayID: String
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870101/swift-sort-an-array-with-strings-and-numbers ?

Comment: I did already see that post. They don't specify how to use that to sort by multiple properties, and I can't work that part out.

Comment: It's not related to "sort by multiple properties", in the end, it's how to compare `ralwayID` when their `elr` are the same, and it's exactly the linked question (with multiple answers to adapt maybe to your case, because it's unclear in where "C0284" would go against "B01", before or after it?)

Comment: So what is the expected result `["10A", "11", "12", "101023", "110032"]` ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am hoping to achieve

Comment: and which property has priority?

Comment: In the case of "C0284" and "B01", I would hope that "B01" would come first.

Comment: ELR has priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a custom sort method. If  ELR elements are equal sort the ralwayID using localized standard compare otherwise just sort by ELR

```
let sorted = sortedDayListItems.sorted {
    if $0.elr == $1.elr {
        return $0.railwayID.localizedStandardCompare($1.railwayID) == .orderedAscending
    }
    return $0.elr < $1.elr
}
```