# Issue with ordering list of objects in an array with different elements in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have the structure which holds the user and their record as seen below:

```
[ 
    UserResults(username: "joluch99", results: [Record(wins: "12", total: "17", tie: "10", percent: "70.58")]), 
    UserResults(username: "bsroberts44", results: [Record(wins: "16", total: "17", tie: "20", percent: "94.11")]),
    UserResults(username: "fmiller", results: [Record(wins: "10", total: "17", tie: "5", percent: "58.83")]),
    UserResults(username: "iguerra", results: [Record(wins: "12", total: "17", tie: "30", percent: "70.58")]),
    ...
]
```

I wish to order the list based on the person with the most wins.

I am not entirely sure how I can achieve that? I have seen examples of sorting when it just a simple array of items?

I have tried the following:

```
self.userResults = self.userResults.sorted(by: { $0.results[0].wins > $1.results[0].wins })
```

Which does not sort the entire list, seems like only the last 2 items in the array get sorted correctly.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE:

My end goal is that the information as seen above is how its pulled from Firebase.

I want to display the list in a View where its ordered by the user with the highest wins.

Comment: Why do you have an array if there is only one result (Record)? Do you expect to sum the result wins or just the highest wins value should be used when sorting?

Comment: Just calculate sum of wins in each UserResults then sort?

Comment: Just the highest wins value.

Comment: So you just need to find the highest wins value of each UserResults then sort based on that.

Comment: @erictruong yes. The highest "wins" value should be first followed by the next users highest wins value and so on and so forth.

Comment: I have tried the following but it does not fully work `self.userResults = self.userResults.sorted( by: { $0.results[0].wins > $1.results[0].wins })`

Comment: "I have tried ..." is a critical part of your question.  Edit your question to say what you tried, then say what you mean by "does not fully work".

Comment: Just because your wins is String, you have to convert it to number

Comment: @Learn2Code you need to use a localizedStandardCompare when comparing strings with numbers https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870210/2303865

Comment: Why are you storing numeric values as `String`s? That makes the code a lot messier. Convert all your numeric values to `Int` or `Double` types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code for sorting your structs would sort based on the first entry in your results array for each `UserResults`:

```
let sortedUsers = users.sorted {Int($0.results[0].wins) ?? 0 > Int($1.results[0].wins) ?? 0 }
```

If you want to go through the array of results for each user and pick the best, it would be a little more complicated, but only a little.

---

### Edit:

After converting your structs to use Int and Double types for numeric values, I added code to sort by ties as well:

```
// Define the Record type using Int and string values.
// Give ties a default value of 0 so we don't have to specify it.
struct Record {
    let wins: Int
    var ties: Int = 0
    let total: Int
    let percent: Double
}

struct UserResults {
    let username: String
    let results: [Record]
}

// Create some test data
let users = [
    UserResults(username: "joluch99", results: [
                    Record(wins: 3, total: 17, percent: 17.64),
                    Record(wins: 23, ties: 14, total: 17, percent: 17.64)]),
     UserResults(username: "bsroberts44",
                 results: [Record(wins: 16, total: 17, percent: 94.11)]),
     UserResults(username: "fmiller",
                 results: [Record(wins: 10, total: 17, percent: 58.83)]),
     UserResults(username: "iguerra", results: [
                    Record(wins: 12, total: 17, percent: 70.58),
        Record(wins: 23, ties: 12, total: 17, percent: 70.58),
     ]),
 ]


let sortedUsers = users.sorted {lhv, rhv in
    // Find the max record for the left hand item being compared
    let lhvMax = lhv.results.max(by: { ($0.wins, $0.ties) < ($1.wins, $1.ties) })!

    // Find the max record for the right hand item being compared.
    let rhvMax = rhv.results.max(by: { ($0.wins, $0.ties)  < ($1.wins, $1.ties) })!

    // Compare tuples containing the win count and ties count for the max record for the lefthand User and the righthand User being compared
    return (lhvMax.wins, lhvMax.ties) > (rhvMax.wins, rhvMax.ties)
}

sortedUsers.forEach { print ($0) }
```

Comment: it worked like a charm! Question if I wanted to now sort by a second element, lets say a "tie breaker" how would I go about that?

Comment: I modified the structs to include the "tie" in the instance the users have an equal number for "wins"

Comment: So if 2 users have the same number of wins, the one with the most ties should be first?

Comment: why not simply using numeric options while comparing the elements `($0.results.first?.wins ?? "").compare($1.results.first?.wins ?? "", options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending`

Comment: @DuncanC just use a tuple :)