# How can I sort an Array of String format of Int Type in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an Array of String which this Array of String is in fact an Array of Int, I want sort this Array of String with this code:

```
let array: [String] = ["13", "8", "10", "12", "3", "7", "1", "2", "11", "9", "6", "4", "5", "1000", "100", "0"].sorted(by: { (value1, value2) in return (value1 < value2) })
```

but out put is:

```
["0", "1", "10", "100", "1000", "11", "12", "13", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

I could use `(Int(value1) < Int(value2))` for solving issue, but it is not practical in massive array size!

How can I sort my array without having to convert it to **Int**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **localizedStandardCompare** method to sort like this.

```
array.sort {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending }
output: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "100", "1000"]
```

Comment: Wow. localizedStandardCompare should be used whenever file names or other strings are presented in lists and tables where Finder-like sorting is appropriate in documents

Comment: @Cruz https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870210/2303865

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NSString.compare(_:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410893-compare) method to compare strings numerically. That will correctly handle leading zeros and similar problems.

```
let array = ["13", "8", "10", "12", "3", "7", "1", "2", "11", "9", "6", "4", "5", "1000", "100", "0"]
let sortedArray = array.sorted { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }

print(sortedArray) // ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "100", "1000"]
```

Comment: IMO options numeric is only useful when sorting floating point values otherwise I just use localized standard compare.

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't like `localizedStandardCompare` because the documentation does not really state what the behavior of the method is and it also state that it can change with future releases.

Comment: I understand but they say it does a finder like sorting and it wouldn’t make any sense to change that behavior