# Swift Sort string array with german localization

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, localization

I am sorting an array of Strings in alphabetical order (first two letters) for a tableview and don't know how to sort with german localization.

When changing localization to german in xcode the sort function does puts all the "umlaut" of the second letter at the end of the second letter.

This is the output:

SORTED NAMES ARRAY
["Ebersbach, Dirk", "Essmann, Christoph", "Fallheim, Silke", "Foerster, Thomas", "Frutteln, Dr. Hans", "Förster, Prof. Dr. Farsin", "Gardeia, Christiane", "Grünelt, Mario", "Hennig, Kristin", "Hoßfeldt, Ivonne", "Lange, Kati", "Liebschwager, Georg", "Loth, Stefan", "Ludwig, Dr.Volker", "Michaelis, Nicole", "Neißhardt, Claudia", "Niepel, Mandy", "Nützer, Jens", "Patientenaufnahme D", "Patientenaufnahme FR/C", "Patientenaufnahme Ortho/BV", "Qasem, Mohammed", "Raschke, Steffen", "Riebel, Heike", "Riedel, Simona", "Schreiner, Dirk", "Seidel, Antje", "Sieler, Christian", "Zühlke, Dr. Kati"]

The sort function is this:

```
var bez = [String]()

let sortedBez = bez.sorted(by: {
            $0.lowercased() < $1.lowercased() } )
```

But the in the sorted output array "Förster, Prof. Dr. Farsin" (element 5 of sorted array) should come after "Foerster, Thomas" (as element 4 of sorted array).

Ho do I achieve this ? I already tried to change localization setting of xcode to german but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a [`String.Comparator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/comparator) to `sort`.

```
bez.sorted(using: String.Comparator(
    options: .caseInsensitive/*, locale: Locale(identifier: "de")*/
))
```

Without the `locale:` argument, this already sorts "Fö" immediately after "Foe". If you specifically want to use the collation rules of the German locale, you can add the `locale:` argument too.

You can also sort the strings in the way Finder sorts file names, by using the [`localizedStandard`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/comparator/localizedstandard) comparator:

```
bez.sorted(using: .localizedStandard)
```

Comment: I think `sorted(using: .localizedStandard)` should suffice. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870210/2303865)

Comment: @LeoDabus I contemplated adding that in, but `.localizedStandard` uses the current locale, and there is no case insensitive option, and it also sorts numbers differently, so it's *slightly* different than what the OP asked. I guess I'll add it in anyway, seeing your comment.

Comment: @Sweeper localizedStandard is case and diacritic insensitive