# How to Properly Sort Array of Objects on Numeric Property

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, format

I have an array of objects like this, but with 16 properties:

```
class anObject: NSObject {
   @objc var number: Int
   @objc var name: String
   @objc var price: Double

   subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
       return self.value(forKey: key)
   }
}
```

I am able to sort my array on any property very easily by, for instance:

```
sortedArray = unsortedArray.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name } )
```

Now I am grouping my array so that I can populate a UITableView with sections and rows. I group it like this:

```
var groupedArray = Dictionary<String, Array<myObject>>()

for item in myArray {
    // Verify each grouping is initialized only once    
    if groupedArray[item[byProperty] as! String] == nil {
        groupedArray[item[byProperty] as! String] = Array<Items>()
    }

    // Add the item into the correct subarray
    groupedArray[item[byProperty] as! String]?.append(item)
}
```

I can then sort the grouped array by doing this:

```
return groupedArray.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

And this works great, except that two of my properties are Doubles. When I sort on those two properties, Swift sorts the groups alphabetically:

```
10.5, 11.5, 12, 1.5, 2.0 . . .
```

rather than numerically

```
1.5, 2.0, 10.5, 11.5, 12 . . .
```

I have managed to pad the Doubles by checking to see if they are too short and inserting a 0 at the front of the String. This works in that they are now sorted in correct order, but eventually I am going to have to strip that leading 0 off the front, and it seems like an ugly solution.

How do I properly sort the grouped array given that the Doubles have to be used as Strings?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/39748677/1187415

Comment: Are all the keys in the dictionary going to be the same type stored as a string?  As in will it always be all stringed integers, doubles, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

When you start casting strings all over the place, you likely need to start changing the design of things.  Why not make the dictionary keys some object you've designed instead of a string?  This is a sample of what I mean:

```
struct DoubleKey {
    let value: Double
}
extension DoubleKey: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return value.hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: DoubleKey, rhs: DoubleKey) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
}
extension DoubleKey: Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: DoubleKey, rhs: DoubleKey) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value < rhs.value
    }
}

let a = DoubleKey(value: 10.0)
let b = DoubleKey(value: 20.0)
let c = DoubleKey(value: -10.0)
let dictionary: [DoubleKey: String] = [a: "10", b: "20", c: "-10"]
let sortedDictionary = dictionary.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

So instead of `[String: Array<myobject>]` you have: `[DoubleKey: Array<MyObject>` or `[IntegerKey: Array<MyObject>]` or even `[StringKey: Array<MyObject>`

You could implement many variations of your own specialized key, and write some protocols if you need additional functionality.  If you need to store a string in your key, then add a property, or better yet, conform it to a protocol that defines the behavior of what you need and implement it.

---

**Additional Key**

```
struct StringKey {
    let value: String
}
extension StringKey: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return value.hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: StringKey, rhs: StringKey) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
}
extension StringKey: Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: StringKey, rhs: StringKey) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value < rhs.value
    }
}

let a = StringKey(value: "a")
let b = StringKey(value: "c")
let c = StringKey(value: "b")
let dictionary: [StringKey: String] = [a: "10", b: "20", c: "-10"]
let sortedDictionary = dictionary.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

---

**Now what?**

```
//EXAMPLE
protocol ViewableString {
    func view() -> String
}

extension StringKey: ViewableString {
    func view() -> String {
        return value
    }
}

extension DoubleKey: ViewableString {
    func view() -> String {
        return String(value)
    }
}

let array: [ViewableString] = [a, b, c]
array[0].view()
```

Program to the protocols!

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I tried to make my Key an Any so I could use either a String or a Double, but Any isn't Hashable. It seems like I need a key that could be either of two types, String or Double. I like your suggestion, but not sure how to modify what you wrote.

Comment: I'll add some more for you

Comment: @AugustDanowski Added some stuff.

Comment: @AugustDanowski Don't use any, use the explicit type.  Why do you need to use Any?  Are the keys you're storing have to include Strings and Doubles in the same Dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Completely different answer.  Again, you are trying to fit many objects of different types in the same container.  This feels like a bad idea to me.  Maybe you have to.  But here is one way using enums:

```
enum SpecialKey {
    case integer(Int)
    case double(Double)
    case string(String)

    func asString() -> String {
        switch self {
            case let .integer(a):
                return String(a)
            case let .double(a):
                return String(a)
            case let .string(a):
                return a
        }
    }
}
extension SpecialKey: Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: SpecialKey, rhs: SpecialKey) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.double(a), .double(b)):
            return a < b
        case let (.integer(a), .integer(b)):
            return a < b
        case let (.string(a), .string(b)):
            return a < b
        default:
            return false //Add more cases with different comparisons!
        }
    }

    static func ==(lhs: SpecialKey, rhs: SpecialKey) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
            case (.integer(_), .integer(_)),
                 (.double(_), .double(_)),
                 (.string(_), .string(_)):
                return true
            default:
                return false
        }
    }
}

extension SpecialKey: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case let .integer(a):
            return a.hashValue
        case let .double(a):
            return a.hashValue
        case let .string(a):
            return a.hashValue
        }
    }
}

let a = SpecialKey.integer(10)
let b = SpecialKey.string("something")
let c = SpecialKey.double(10.5)
let dictionary: [SpecialKey: String] = [a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"]
```

This is probably more like what you're looking for.