# Swift: sort an array of strings...of more or less numbers

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

I have an array of strings, examples are as follows:

```
"0.125-0.25"
"1-2"
"50-100"
"100-200"
```

The result of sorting these is:

```
"0.125-0.25"
"1-2"
"100-200"
"50-100"
```

And if I append("1000-2000") to the array and then sort it will be:

```
"0.125-0.25"
"1-2"
"100-200"
"1000-2000"
"50-100"
```

But what I want is:

```
"0.125-0.25"
"1-2"
"50-100"
"100-200"
"1000-2000"
```

It's definitely an edge case, but I have been having luck on my own.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Do you consider `1-2` bigger or smaller than `1.5-2.5`? What about `1-2` and `1.1-1.2`?

Comment: This is related https://stackoverflow.com/q/31209195/1187415, but is does not handle floating point numbers.

Comment: How do you sort it now? Why can't you just split by "-", convert to Float and sort whatever you like?

Comment: In future, please take time to review your question and format any code, data, etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I hoping to just be able pass something simple to .sort().  But looks like I have to go with an intermediate object, even if it is only an array of doubles.

@Sweeper, I'd say 1-2 is smaller.  Just using the first value will work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

A working but not very efficient solution is to extract the first Double value in the string ranges and sort by them. It's very inefficient because in each call of the closure both Double values have to be recreated.

```
var array = ["1-2", "50-100", "0.125-0.25", "100-200"]
array.append("1000-2000")

let sortedArray = array.sorted { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
    func firstDouble(of string: String) -> Double { return Double(string.components(separatedBy: "-").first!)! }
    return firstDouble(of: str1) < firstDouble(of: str2)
}

print(sortedArray)
```

A more efficient solution is to map the array (once) to its first Double value, then `zip` both arrays, sort the combined array by the Double array and map the result back to the string-range array.

```
var array = ["1-2", "50-100", "0.125-0.25", "100-200"]
array.append("1000-2000")

let firstDoubleArray = array.map{Double($0.components(separatedBy: "-").first!)!}
let sortedArray = zip(array, firstDoubleArray).sorted {$0.1 < $1.1}.map{$0.0}

print(sortedArray)
```

Comment: What is the separator could be anything on UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation?  Can (separatedBy: String) take an array of Strings as the separator?

Comment: Hm, doesn't look like it can: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-components

Comment: It can: there is also a `components(separatedBy separator: CharacterSet)` API. The contents of the character set can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

What it appears you're sorting is ranges of `Double`s, so the problem can be clarified by creating an intermediate object…

```
struct DoubleRange: Comparable {
    let start: Double
    let end: Double

    init(string: String) {
        let components = string.split(separator: "-")
        start = Double(components[0])! // Be careful with `!` here, I'm assuming the format is always correct
        end = Double(components[1])!
    }

    var stringValue: String {
        return "\(start)-\(end)"
    }

    static func < (lhs: DoubleRange, rhs: DoubleRange) -> Bool {
        return lhs.start < rhs.start
    }
}
```

Then sorting is simple…

```
var array = ["1-2", "50-100", "0.125-0.25", "100-200"]
array.append("1000-2000")

array.map(DoubleRange.init).sorted().map{$0.stringValue}

// ["0.125-0.25", "1.0-2.0", "50.0-100.0", "100.0-200.0", "1000.0-2000.0"]
```

And if you always want to convert back to the string value, you could add…

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    func sortedDoubleRange() -> [String] {
        return array.map(DoubleRange.init).sorted().map{$0.stringValue}
    }
}

array.sortedDoubleRange()
```

Be careful with this though… it will crash if any of strings are formatted incorrectly.

Comment: No, see thats the thing.  The separator could be "-" or "/" or a few other things the user chooses.  Though I suppose I could filter the input...

Comment: There was no mention of that in the original question. In that case split the string using `.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet)`. Or get the user to input 2 separate strings (containing `Double`s)

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned it.  I just changed the UI and now have two text fields and am storing the values as doubles and sorting on the first value.  It just seems best.  Thank you though,.