# Tableview is not sorting once number is above 10

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm sorting tableview using this code:

```
list.sort() { $0.points > $1.points }
```

And everything works fine (For a bit)
If I use this sort method it's sorting numbers (aka points) all the way up to 10. But once a number is above 10, the list is not getting sorted anymore. And I've no idea how to solve this issue.

Result under 10:

[image: 1]

Result above 10:

[image: 2]

I guess it's being placed where it is because of "10", if I would use like "60" it would be placed under the 2nd or 3rd spot. So, how can I solve this? I would be very thankful for it.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Sorting array alphabetically with number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209195/sorting-array-alphabetically-with-number).

Comment: The better solution would be to store the points as *integers* instead of strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the normal behavior when comparing strings. Strings are not numbers.

The method [`localizedStandardCompare`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409742-localizedstandardcompare) compares like in `Finder` and handles numeric strings correctly

```
list.sort() { $0.points.localizedStandardCompare($1.points) == .orderedDescending }
```

Alternatively [`compare`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408732-compare) with [`.numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1415530-numeric) option

```
list.sort() { $0.points.compare($1.points, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending }
```

Comment: Ohhhh, I see! Thanks a lot for your input. I'll accept the question in 9 minutes. Thanks a lot for the help of yours!